# Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to load ZF2 - error on WAMP

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm new to ZEND FW2.

I am following some tutorials to gain knowledge...  recently I have created a new ZEND project on Netbeans. When I run the project it gives me the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to load ZF2. Run `php 
>       composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.

I have installed Zend Skeleton Application on Net-beans

any idea on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must include ZF library in your PHP include_path

see this for more information :

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/ref/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

In case of Plesk:

```
Subscriptions > domain.tld > PHP settings
```

[image: plesk windows Zend include_path]